# "Положительная энергетика" или "положительная энергия"?

Tags: грамотная-речь, выбор-слов

Выражение "положительная энергетика" довольно часто попадается на глаза. Зачастую я не понимаю, почему *энергетика*, а не *энергия*.  Я нашел 9 вхождений со словом *энергетика* в Нацкорусе. Приведу их с моими комментариями:

> 1. [Лилия Рэйман, nick] От Вас всегда исходит мощная, положительная **энергетика**, это ощущается даже через монитор. [коллективный. Форум: Обсуждение статьи М. Прохорова «О «надомниках» и трудоголиках. Или как они живут совместно в нашем ТК» (2010)]

Непонятно, почему исходит энергетика, а не энергия. Ошибка?

> 2. Брежнева может играть актер с положительной **энергетикой**, с положительным обаянием, с Горбачевым та же история. [Константин Мильчин. Чекисты с лицами бомжей // «Русский репортер», № 43 (122), 12-19 ноября 2009, 2009]

Здесь я не вижу возможности заменить *энергетику* на *энергию* (Если считать, что *энергетика* — некое энергетическое состояние человека).

> 3. Взглядом я выразил свою честность и открытость, сообщил положительную **энергетику**, попытался послать глазами прямо в лоб своему клетчатому земляку заряд веселой силы и уверенности в собственной правоте. [Андрей Рубанов. Сажайте, и вырастет (2005)]

В каком смысле сообщил? Если послал, то почему не *энергию*?  Ошибка?

> 4. Все, кто хоть раз побывал здесь, хотят вернуться вновь. Здесь необыкновенная аура, положительная **энергетика** земли. И людей у нас талантливых много. [Виктор Токарев. Мы старались дать зрителям надежду (2004) // «Театральная жизнь», 2004.02.23]

Возможно, здесь *энергетика* – некое энергетическое состояние земли. Хотя, можно было бы сказать "положительная энергия" (излучаемая землей).

> 5. …Северная вышивка и берестоплетение, объемная резьба и роспись по дереву, плетение из корня и лоскутная мозаика были представлены настолько ярко, самобытно и привлекательно, что все хотелось потрогать, подержать в руках, согреться положительной **энергетикой**, содержащейся в каждом выставочном экспонате. [Тепло русского Севера (2004) // «Народное творчество», 2004.06.21]

По-моему, согревает все-таки *энергия*, а не *энергетика*. Ошибка?

> 6. Может, поэтому ротанговая мебель несет положительную **энергетику**? [Татьяна Ефимова. Для полного счастья (2003) // «Ландшафтный дизайн», 2003.05.15]

Может, и несет (если *энергетика* — некое энергетическое состояние мебели).

> 7. Положительная **энергетика** пропитывается и проникает во все окружающее, вплоть до атомов, уничтожая и прогоняя вредную, отрицательную энергию. [Алексей Яшкин. Программа индульгирования. Оздоровление организма, развитие силы воли, силы духа, храбрости и смелости каратиста (2003) // «Боевое искусство планеты», 2003.12.08]

*Энергетика* уничтожет *энергию*? Образец псевдонаучной заумности?

> 8. Даже на остатках фундаментов или на холмах, где некогда высились замки, ощущаешь сильную положительную **энергетику**. [Марина Лацис. Маэстро готики (2002) // «Ландшафтный дизайн», 2002.07.15]

Возможно, простые люди вроде меня, способны ощущать *энергию*, а более продвинутые — *энергетику* (опять таки понимаемую как энергетическое состояние среды)? Мне достаточно, чтобы в меня вливалась положительная *энергия*, поэтому я бы об *энергии* и писал.

> 9. Но как ни парадоксально, мощь прорыва в работах Бурлюка импульсирует положительной **энергетикой**. [Арина Абросимова. Блудный отец (2001) // «Аргументы и факты», 2001.04.04]

Импульсировать – это посылать импульсы? Ну тогда импульсы *энергии*, а не *энергетики*. Ошибка?

А что говорят словари?

> [ЭНЕРГЕТИКА](http://gramota.ru/slovari/dic/?word=%D1%8D%D0%BD%D0%B5%D1%80%D0%B3%D0%B5%D1%82%D0%B8%D0%BA%D0%B0&all=x) [нэ], -и; ж. Область хозяйства, охватывающая выработку, преобразование, передачу и использование различных видов энергии. Развитие энергетики. Атомная э.

Если верить этому словарю, все 9 вхождений надо признать некорректными.

> [Значение слова ЭНЕРГЕТИКА в Толковом словаре Ефремовой](https://slovar.cc/rus/efremova-tolk/380911.html): 3) перен. Характер жизненной энергии, присущей человеку.

Очень туманно. Почему характер, почему только человеку? Мое понимание: ЭНЕРГЕТИКА — это некое энергетическое состояние, наполненность энергией (относится к человеку, предметам, земле, окружающей среде и т. д.)

Помогите разобраться.

Answer (score 1):

**Положительная и отрицательная энергетика** - термины из эзотерики. Наша Вселенная - огромный резервуар энергии. Бесчисленное количество квантов, образуя мощные потоки, насыщает Вселенную энергией и образует общее энергетическое поле Вселенной.

Что же такое энергетика человека? Это его жизненная сила, которая складывается из двух составляющих энергии: внешней и внутренней — телесной и духовной. Телесная во многом зависит от окружающего мира, от экологии, от пищи и воды, которые мы употребляем, от действий, которые мы совершаем. Духовная же зависит от нашего внутреннего состояния — эмоциональной стабильности и позитивных или негативных мыслей и намерений. Телесная энергия аккумулирует внутреннюю, духовную энергию и направляет ее вовне. Наше тело в идеале проводник нашего Духа. Не зря же говорят что гармония начинается изнутри.

Все существующее в мире – человека, льва, рыбу, камень, дом или планету – окружает **индивидуальное энергетическое поле.** Это и есть  энергетика или биоэнергетика (для живых существ). Свойства поля исследованы далеко не в полной мере, но для того, чтобы использовать энергетику живого и неживого для своих целей, практические знания человечества о ней вполне достаточны. Вся жизнь людей состоит в обмене энергией и информацией с окружающей средой. Человек, умеющий делать это лучше других, более гармонично вписывается в окружающий мир и получает больше удачи, материальных и духовных благ, счастья и здоровья. Чтобы улучшить собственную жизнь, надо научиться жить в гармонии с энергетикой природы.
На Востоке энергетику называют ци, чи, прана и много тысячелетий используют для восстановления и сохранения здоровья, улучшения жизни и достижения счастья.

**Положительная энергетика соответствует человеку с позитивным характером и мировоззрением.** Прежде всего, такому человеку свойственны чистые искренние намерения и чистые мысли. **Поле такого человека наполнено светом и искрящейся энергией.** Рядом с таким человеком заряжаешься положительными эмоциями, и происходит психическая стабилизация неуравновешенного состояния.

В лингвистической практике слова энергетика и энергия часто подменяют. Разберём Ваши примеры.

1. От Вас всегда исходит мощная, положительная энергетика, это ощущается даже через монитор.

`Непонятно, почему исходит энергетика, а не энергия. Ошибка?`

Не совсем, поле тоже распространяется, можно сказать "исходит положительный заряд психической энергии", а психическая энергия - это уже энергетика, а не энергия тела.

2. Брежнева может играть актер с положительной энергетикой, с положительным обаянием, с Горбачевым та же история.

Всё верно.

3. Взглядом я выразил свою честность и открытость, сообщил положительную энергетику, попытался послать глазами прямо в лоб своему клетчатому земляку заряд веселой силы и уверенности в собственной правоте.

Сообщил -  т.е передал положительное психическое состояние. Употреблено верно.

4. Все, кто хоть раз побывал здесь, хотят вернуться вновь. Здесь необыкновенная аура, положительная энергетика земли. И людей у нас талантливых много.

Всё верно, положительная энергетика, т.е. здоровая, гармоничная. Здесь всем хорошо.

5. …Северная вышивка и берестоплетение, объемная резьба и роспись по дереву, плетение из корня и лоскутная мозаика были представлены настолько ярко, самобытно и привлекательно, что все хотелось потрогать, подержать в руках, согреться положительной энергетикой, содержащейся в каждом выставочном экспонате. [Тепло русского Севера (2004) // «Народное творчество», 2004.06.21]

`По-моему, согревает все-таки энергия, а не энергетика. Ошибка?`

Вероятно, можно сказать и энергией, и энергетикой. Говорим же мы "согреться добротой", а доброта - добрая энергетика, поле доброты.

6. Может, поэтому ротанговая мебель несет положительную энергетику? [Татьяна Ефимова. Для полного счастья (2003) // «Ландшафтный дизайн», 2003.05.15]

Всё верно, несёт положительную энергетику, т.е. от неё нам хорошо.

7. Положительная энергетика пропитывается и проникает во все окружающее, вплоть до атомов, уничтожая и прогоняя вредную, отрицательную энергию. [Алексей Яшкин. Программа индульгирования. Оздоровление организма, развитие силы воли, силы духа, храбрости и смелости каратиста (2003)

Здесь мне не нравится "пропитывается", -ся нужно убрать. А что поле положительной энергии  проникает и прогоняет плохую энергию - это верно.

8. Даже на остатках фундаментов или на холмах, где некогда высились замки, ощущаешь сильную положительную энергетику.

Всё верно, ощущаешь положительное психическое состояние - энергетику.

9. Но как ни парадоксально, мощь прорыва в работах Бурлюка импульсирует положительной энергетикой. [Арина Абросимова. Блудный отец (2001) // «Аргументы и факты», 2001.04.04]

`Импульсировать – это посылать импульсы? Ну тогда импульсы энергии, а не энергетики. Ошибка?`

Поле может посылать импульсы, так что ошибки нет.

Comment: Все это очень интересно, благодарно ставлю плюс. Однако где выход в лингвистическую практику? Когда верно употреблять слово  "энергетика", а когда "энергия"? В Вашем  ответе, кстати, есть и то и другое.

Comment: А в лингвистической практике люди, использующие эти слова, Вы правы,  подчас их путают и подменяют энергетику энергией.

Answer (score 0):

Как видно из словаря Ефремовой, **энергетика** ― это во многих случаях просто  технический термин, связанный с понятием энергии.

ЭНЕРГИЯ [нэ], -и; ж. [от греч. enérgeia ― деятельность] 1. Одно из главных свойств материи - **количественная мера движения** и взаимодействия материальных тел (имеет различные формы: механическую, тепловую, электромагнитную, ядерную и др.). Закон сохранения энергии.  2. **Способность какого-л. тела, вещества и т.п. производить какую-л. работу**  Э. потока воды. 3. **Способность активно, настойчиво действовать**, трудиться и т.п.; деятельная сила человека. Отличаться большой энергией. Подъём энергии. Взяться за что-л. с энергией. Заразить всех своей энергией. Умственная, физическая, нравственная э. 4. чего. **Сила проявления, интенсивность** чего-л. Э. ума. Э. мысли. Э. чувств.

Итак, энергия ― это мера движения, интенсивность действия, **причем в различных сферах.** Можно, к примеру, говорить **об  энергии духа**.

А вот слово **энергетика** (в переносном значении) мы используем в особых случаях, когда говорим о **позитивной (положительной) энергетике** (как известно, энергию положительной не называют, она не имеет знака). Речь в этом случае идет **о   биоэнергии живых существ (людей, животных, растений):** это светлая **положительная**  энергия или ее отсутствие, которая воспринимается нами как **негативная** потенциальная яма.

В обществе людей с положительной энергетикой или при общении с предметами, наполненными энергетикой их творцов, человек также заряжается, чувствует подъем, в то время как "энергетические вампиры" (люди, предметы) могут привести к депрессии, к проявлению негативных чувств.

Comment: Две цитаты: "Энергию положительной не называют",  "это светлая положительная энергия" (?!)

Comment: Обычную энергию положительной не называют, но биоэнергетика - другое дело. Она ощущается  по воздействию на наше энергетическое состояние и называется позитивной, когда вызывает у нас подъем энергии. Говорят, что люди с позитивной энергетикой заряжают остальных  своей энергией.

Answer (score 0):

[**Энергия**](http://%D0%BD%D0%BE%D0%B2%D0%BE%D1%81%D1%82%D0%B8.ru-an.info/%D0%BD%D0%BE%D0%B2%D0%BE%D1%81%D1%82%D0%B8/%D0%BD%D0%B5%D0%BE%D0%B1%D1%8A%D1%8F%D1%81%D0%BD%D0%B8%D0%BC%D0%BE%D0%B5-%D1%87%D1%82%D0%BE-%D1%82%D0%B0%D0%BA%D0%BE%D0%B5-%D0%BF%D0%BE%D0%BB%D0%BE%D0%B6%D0%B8%D1%82%D0%B5%D0%BB%D1%8C%D0%BD%D0%B0%D1%8F-%D0%B8-%D0%BE%D1%82%D1%80%D0%B8%D1%86%D0%B0%D1%82%D0%B5%D0%BB%D1%8C%D0%BD%D0%B0%D1%8F-%D1%8D%D0%BD%D0%B5%D1%80%D0%B3%D0%B8%D1%8F/) - *положительная физическая величина*, поэтому при построении аналогий слово плохо сочетается с прямым отрицанием.

**Энергетика** - совокупность процессов, косвенно связанных с *выделением энергии* (физической, психической при деятельности индитвида и т. п.), причём положительно или отрицательно оценивается не сама "энергия", а *следствия* энергетических процессов: полезны они или нет в рассматриваемом контексте (условно: привносят или отбирают энергию). Отсюда более логична "**положительная энергетика**".

Comment: Это же не физика. В изотерике говорят о хорошей и плохой энергии, в этом смысле употребляя  слова "положительная" и "отрицательная".